# Single thread application Waiting for Synchronization in ANTS profiling tool

Tags: c#, synchronization, ants

My windows application is single threaded. I have many calls to DB and working with List which is costing that's fine(I will try to improve it). However when i select Wall-Clock time **Waiting For Synchronization shows 51!%** and worst part is NO source is available, there are 2 important question here

1) Which is this thread which is waiting for Synchronization (GC thread ?)
2) How to Improve this time?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `Console.ReadKey` or `ReadLine` for the app not to close?

Comment: It is a Windows Application